# PHP curl doesn't return all the response

Tags: php, json, curl, truncated

I am trying to use an API in php which (as usual) returns a large json response with the requested data.

#### It works like this:

1) I have to make a post request with the data i want (in a certain format which is not important here) and then,

2) Visit another url where with a get parameter which i get from the response of step one to get the actual data.

The problem is that i tryed both curl() and get_file_contents() to obtain the json data but it seems that i do not get the whole json. I visit the url from my browser and get the json manually and compare and see if the two match.

What can possibly be wrong?

Here is my code:

```
$tp = new TravelPayoutApi();
$req = $tp->request_one_way('en', 'Y', 1,0,0, 'BER', 'PAR', '2017-10-22');
//$req = $tp->requestRoundTrip('en', 'Y', 1,0,0, 'BER', 'PAR', '2017-10-22','2017-10-25');
echo "req =" . $req;

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://api.travelpayouts.com/v1/flight_search"); // $apiURL = "http://api.travelpayouts.com/v1/flight_search";

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json'));                                    

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $req);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

// $response = array();
// echo $response;
$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
$response = json_decode($response, true);
$search_id = $response['search_id'];
echo $search_id;
```

#### This was the part that gets the parameter i need to collect the data

#### Here are my efforts to obtain and echo them:

```
$results = file_get_contents("http://api.travelpayouts.com/v1/flight_search_results?uuid=" . $search_id);
var_dump($results); // to see if this is really json
// $ch1 = curl_init();
// $resultsURL = "http://api.travelpayouts.com/v1/flight_search_results?uuid=" . $search_id;
// echo "This is the results URL:" . $resultsURL;
// curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_URL, $resultsURL);
// curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);

// $results = curl_exec($ch1);
// $results = json_encode($results);
// curl_close($ch1);
```

The commented lines at the and are different scripts i have tried. Take a look at them too.

### EDIT:

Ok, i tried the original curl command the API **(curl -v -H 'Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch' htttp://api.travelpayouts.com/v1/flight_search_results?uuid=my_id_here --compressed)**, and it works like a charm. But it seems that i can not get it to work with php curl. I always get my results truncated. What can i do about this?

My current code to get the results is:

```
$ch1 = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_URL, $resultsURL);
curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch')); 
curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_ENCODING, 'gzip,deflate,sdch');
// curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 0);
//curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 15); // number of seconds to allow curl to execute

$results = curl_exec($ch1);
echo($results);
curl_close($ch1);
```

Comment: check the error log, look if connection haven't timeouted, or you haven't reached memory limit in php.

Comment: `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS`  is for `POST` requests. `GET` request parameters should be part of the `CURLOPT_URL` string.

Comment: @azurinko Which error log do you mean?

Comment: @AlexBlex This is the first request i send to get the search_id parameter, so i use it to retrieve the results. Read the whole text please. I am explaining how it works

Comment: Ah, sorry, my bad. It seems both requests are valid. I'd use tcpdump or wireshark to check what's going on on the TCP level. Are you on *nix or windows?

Comment: What's the return of var_dump($results); Is an empty array or what?

Comment: It may worth to try curl cli first. Do you retrieve the whole response with `curl -i http://api.travelpayouts.com/v1/flight_search_results?uuid=....` ? Is there anything interesting in the response headers?

Comment: @AlexBlex I am on windows currenlty but i can open vbox with *nix. I will try to figure out what is going on with wireshark and cli, nice idea.

Comment: You can try Fiddler on windows. IIRC it works with http only, so it might be a bit too hight level to debug TCP.

Comment: @paokg4 it returns:D:\wamp64\www\traveltool_api.php:173:string '[{"search_id": "c8f5e5a7-093f-45c3-aa8a-d05793264d88", "initiated_at": "2017-10-06 09:09:37.39420", "signature": "68becca8a6e30755e81528bde95bb35c", "affiliate_has_sales": false, "market": "us", "airports": {}, "airlines": {}, "flight_info": {}, "clean_marker": "my_marker", "debug_mode": false, "gates_info": {"123": {"average_rate": 5, "productivity": 0.0, "rates": 100, "currency_code": "eur", "label": "SWISS", "mobile_version": false, "payment_methods": ["card"], "airline_iatas": ["LX"], "is_airline": true}},'... (length=23331).

Answer (score 1):

Since you get data back try the following to check if all the data you want will be inserted to the file.

```
$results = file_get_contents("http://api.travelpayouts.com/v1/flight_search_results?uuid=" . $search_id);
    $fp = fopen($path_to_file, "r");  
    $fileLines = array();
    while (!feof($fp)){
      array_push(fgets($fp),$results);
    } 
    fclose($$fp);
```

Comment: With the code example above you will figure out if it's a post issue (e.g. post max size) from the URL you call or is a view limit because it's a big json as you said.